# Specific "byeditor" string for multiple editors in biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I defined a macro to change the string that specifies the editors in biblatex, in order to print "Ed.". I'm trying to print "Edd." when the entry has more than an editor.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright, twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[style = ext-verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
    
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{AuthorBou, 
  author   = {Bougaev, S. and Bucci, A.},
  title= {Livre en Francois},
  editor = {Antoni, A.},
  date = {1985},
}

@book{AuthorBuc, 
  author   = {Bucci, S.},
  title= {Libro degli errori},
  editor = {Bugatti, B and Antoni, A.},
  date = {1985},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

 \DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
   byeditor = {\autocap{e}d\adddot},
 }


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

I in the second entry I want "Edd." instead of "Ed.". Since there is no `byeditors` BibliographyString to define, I can't find a solution...

Comment: This isn't really what the `byeditor` string is for. The `editor` and `editors` strings contain the relevant abbreviations. Your problem is really about placing them in front of the names rather than after, which is where they tend to be put.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand: can you please provide an example code? It would be very usefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `byeditor` string is not the thing that needs to be changed, as this is simply the string that introduces the names, something like "Edited by " or similar phrase. What you need to do is change the way the editor names themselves are displayed so that you use the `editor` and `editors` strings when the names are displayed. The following does what you want, I think.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright, twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[style = ext-verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
    
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{AuthorBou, 
  author   = {Bougaev, S. and Bucci, A.},
  title= {Livre en Francois},
  editor = {Antoni, A.},
  date = {1985},
}

@book{AuthorBuc, 
  author   = {Bucci, S.},
  title= {Libro degli errori},
  editor = {Bugatti, B and Antoni, A.},
  date = {1985},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

 \DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
   editor = {\autocap{e}d\adddot},
   editors= {\autocap{e}dd\adddot}
 }

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: For complete consistency you'd probably want to change `byeditorx`, `bytranslator+others` and other similar macros as well. This gets boring quickly, but I don't there is a quicker way to do this. The order of the strings is hard-coded in all of those macros.

Comment: @moewe Yes, I knew that but I didn't have time to add them all and thought that this would at least get the ball rolling for the most used cases.  I'll update the answer. Let me know if I've missed any when I have. :)